# How to use Google Maps Static Map API to create travel directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I was wondering if there is a simple way to get Google Map STATIC API to work for directions... I dont really understand how the whole path thing works... But for example i am trying to accomplish this

src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=10&size=256x256&sensor=true&markers=1208+cherokee+royal+oak+mi&markers=348+e+maple+birmingham+mi"

This will display both points on the map it generates but it does not draw a line between the 2 points anyone able to help here?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can use the Google Maps Directions Webservice:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Each request returns a set of routes. Each route has an array of legs. Each leg is a polyline, which you can overlay on the static maps api.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but your response is WAY over my head... The ultimate goal i am looking for here is to run a database through the static map api to generate an image for about 8,000 entries that will show directions from a customers house to the closest local branch for them...

Comment: Using Google's directions, there's no other way I can think of that will accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Have you ever tried [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode)?

This is also a free Map, but this time is interactable by users. And it shows directions also.